# import citations into large document

Tags: bibliographies, citing, chapters, thesis, import

I am writing a thesis.  I want to have chapters as separate files that are compiled into one large (TotalCompile.tex) document.
My main file looks like:

```
\documentclass[12pt,openright, twoside]{report}
\usepackage[subpreambles=true]{standalone}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{import}
\usepackage{fullpage}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\setlength{\headsep}{15mm}
\usepackage{natbib}

\pagenumbering{gobble}% Remove page numbers (and reset to 1)
\title{A Physical and Numerical Study of an Interconnected Wave Energy Array}
\author{Ben Howey}
\date{\today}

\begin{document}
\maketitle
\newpage

\chapter{Literature Review}
\pagenumbering{arabic}% Arabic page numbers (and reset to 1)
\import{Literature_Review_Dir/}{Litterature_Review.tex}

\end{document}
```

My Literature_Review.tex looks like  this:

```
\documentclass[float=false, crop=false]{standalone}
\usepackage[subpreambles=true]{standalone}
\usepackage{import}
\usepackage{fullpage}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{natbib}

\bibliographystyle{unsrtnat}

\begin{document}

This section will review will give a broad overview of the potential resource and why wave energy is a commodity worthy of focused research \cite{greg10}

\bibliography{LitReviewBib}

\end{document}
```

The document compiles but it says that all of the citations are undefined!  I want to include a bibliography at the end of each chapter in my main document and be able to separately compile each chapter including all citations.  How can this be done?

EDIT: Thanks for your replies @marmot and @Mico. I have added the `\bibliography{LitReviewBib}` line to the literature review document that I forgot to put into the example above! The literature review compiles fine with all refs. The Total Compile does not! I get the following error:

> ```
> ! LaTeX Error: \NAT@idxtxt undefined.See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX
> Companion for explanation.Type H for immediate help....
> \AtBeginDocument{\NAT@set@cites}
> ```

and

> ```
> ! LaTeX Error: Command \NAT@idxtxt already defined.Or name \end...
> illegal, see p.192 of the manual.See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX
> Companion for explanation.Type H for immediate help....
> ...AT@spacechar\NAT@open\NAT@date\NAT@close}
> ```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. Did you run BibTeX, followed by two more LaTeX runs?

Comment: @marmot - I'd say that `\bibliographystyle{unsrtnat}` is a dead give-away. :-) The fact that the `natbib` package is loaded also pretty much also allows only one kind of conclusion. You're right, though, that the absence of a `\bibliography` command is going to be fatal to the effort to create a bibliography.

Comment: @Mico Yup, that's probably the reason that there are no references in. So the OP needs to do both, add an appropriate `\bibliography` command, and follow your instructions on the bibtex and latex runs.

Answer (score 1):

You get the error `! LaTeX Error: \NAT@idxtxt undefined.` if `\usepackage{natbib}` is missing from the main document. standalone then tries to load it with `\AtBeginDocument` and this doesn't work with natbib.

So add

```
 \usepackage{natbib}
```

always also to the preamble of your main file.